# Asking about a concept in Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am preparing for a masters entrance and the following type of  questions are asked a lot in the exam.

Consider this question: Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix . Is the statement

> For all non-zero vectors $v, w\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $(Aw)^T (Av)>0$

true? Why or why not?

I am not very good in linear algebra but practice a lot of question now a days.

Can you please answer this question and tell me  what is this concept that involves  $(Aw)^T (Av)>0$ called? I have been seeing a lot of these type of questions where something related to $(Aw)^T (Av)>0$  is asked.

Thank you!

Comment: No. Let $A$ be the identity matrix and let $v$ and $w$ be any two vectors whose dot product is negative.

Comment: If the quantity is positive for some $v$ it would be negative for $-v$.

Comment: That positivity condition is eerily similar to positive definiteness. However, I believe the notion of positive definiteness is usually defined only for symmetric matrices. OP: You might want to look up what a positive definite matrix is.

Comment: I think your statement is a bit off. But you can think through how any inner product will correspond to a matrix representation such that $<v,w>=(Aw)\cdot(Av)$ where $\cdot$ represents dot-product.

Comment: $(Aw)^T(Av)>0 \rightarrow w^TA^TAv >0$. now lets suppose we introduce a $P = A^TA$. Hereby it can be stated that $P$ is a symmetric matrix. Additionally the following can be stated: if $A$ is invertible, $P$ is a positive definite matrix, otherwise a semi-positive definite matrix (atleast one eigenvalue is 0). Positive definiteness means that for any non-zero vector $x$, $x^TPx > 0$. while this starts to closely re-ensemble your statement, there is that small difference that $v \neq w$. Therefore, as @JohnDouma stated, the statement is false.